# Robolectric 3 support of Gradle splits

Tags: android, gradle, robolectric

I have in `build.gradle` Android splits:

```
    splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'mips', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi'
        universalApk false
    }
}


android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // assign different version code for each output
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.versionCodeOverride =
                versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 1000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
    }
}
```

After update of `Robolectric` to `3.0` I become path error:

```
build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml not found or not a file; it should point to your project's AndroidManifest.xml
```

because I in build/intermediates/manifests/full/ have 4 splits folders

```
      armeabi/     armeabi-v7a/ mips/        x86/
```

How can i set in `Robolectric` config or in `gradle` configuration, that I have splits?

Thank you

UPDATE:
In all my classes I have following configuration:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(sdk = 21, manifest = "../application/AndroidManifest.xml", constants = BuildConfig.class)
```

Comment: How do you run test?

Comment: With testDebug gradle task

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way will just be to point it to your `x86/AndroidManifest.xml`

You can specify this using the `manifest` key in your `@Config`, e.g.

```
@Config(manifest="path-here")
```

Since you will need this for every test, you might also consider creating a properties file. For more details on this, the docs are [here](http://robolectric.org/configuring/)

Comment: Thank you, I can make some workaround and set the path to manifest direct to some context, for example to arm oder x86, but my question was: how can I use my test for all platforms?

Comment: Well, Robolectric tests run on the JVM, not on actual devices, so you can't really test the other platforms the way you're thinking.

Comment: Yes, i know and this is an advantage, but in my code I use different calls. Ok, I try to use the same Manifest to all flavors.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand, do you have different Java code that depends on the underlying architecture and you want to be able to trigger those specific code branches and test each of them?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want